# Knp Paginator underscore in table name problem?

Tags: php, knppaginator

I was very happy when I found how simple pagination can be with this bundle. But after few days I encountered a problem. I get error about unexisting table.

I installed Knp Paginator bundle in symfony 3.4 implement it for a few classes. Now I have class AppBundle\Entity\HAddress. And bundle understand it's name wrong way. This is my Entity(part of it):

```
/**
 * HAddress
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="h_address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\HAddressRepository")
 * @Table(indexes={@Index(columns={"house_number", "street"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
 */
class HAddress
```

This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
        // Not important for this
    if(isset($searchString) && !empty($searchString)) {
        // Not important for this
    } else {
        $find = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("AppBundle:HAddress")->createQueryBuilder("p");     <-------------Here is the problem

        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $query = $em->createQuery($find);

        /** @var "Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator" */
        $hAddresses = $paginator->paginate(
            $query            <----------- And Here
        );
    }

    return $this->render('haddress/index.html.twig', array(
```

And on loading page I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(DISTINCT h0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM haddress h0_':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'horus.haddress' doesn't exist

From anotation above it is clear that table name is "h_address" and not "haddress". Is this some kind of naming convention i dont know some config setup i missed or a bug?

Please if you know how help me to solve this issue. **What to do so Knp Paginator see and use correct table name?**

Comment: Oh, sorry people, I just noticed that i did not update db after adding those full text indexes. After fixing that things worked

Comment: Hello @bibi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post your solution (as trivial as it may be) as answer and accept it? It might help future viewers of the page who just skip the comments and do not see your solution in the comments.

Comment: If it is good for you..

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry people, I just noticed that i did not update database after adding those full text indexes:

```
* @Table(indexes={@Index(columns={"house_number", "street"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
```

After running

> doctrine:schema:update --force

things worked fine.